# DLNA/UPNP server with tag support?

Tags: media, ps3, tags, upnp, dlna

I'm looking for a DLNA server that allows tagging media and then browsing by those tags.

I have a large media library (music, videos, photos) on a server and I use my PS3 to view it. Let's say I have a photo of 3 people. I'd like to tag the photo with their names so that I can later find all photos of each person. Similarly, I'd like to be able to tag videos by year, genre, actors, etc.

I'm currently using PS3 Media Server, which is very simple and powerful, but doesn't offer this sort of customization.

The best case scenario would be a standalone server that I could "point" to my existing media server, and that would allow me to add the tags I want in a simple GUI on my server. Then, on the PS3, I would see both servers, with the new one having tag folders instead of the regular ones. Selecting an item in this new server would simply link me to the other one. I don't know if this is at all possible.

Maybe I'm just over-thinking this, so if a simpler solution exists I'm open to suggestions.

By the way I did look at the source code for PS3 Media Server but I'm more of a .net developer and I didn't find the code very attractive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to roll my own. It's a pretty interesting project, allowing me to learn about UPnP.

Comment: Hey, what did you end up going with?

Comment: @GiH, I started programming my own server that would talk with ps3 media server and reorganise it. While it was fun to do, I lost interest and never completed it. But I learned UPNP along the way!